# Laravel controller not found 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm working on Laravel 5.7 project and I'm trying to create a controller with this name AdminController with this command "php artisan make:controller foldername\AdminController" then I give it a route like this Route::get('/admin','AdminController@login');

the thing is I can't find the AdminController in my project folders? I searched in App/Http/Controller also it's not there?

Comment: Are you using git? You could run `git status` to show new files

Comment: no, I'm not using git!!

Comment: Can you show us your folder structure?

Comment: If you don't use `foldername` and only give the controller name is there any difference?

Comment: Folder structure https://ibb.co/nMZGy3n

Comment: even withoud the foldername no thing different!

Comment: Controller folder https://ibb.co/Jkw1Ypd

Comment: you can use Route::get('/admin','foldername/AdminController@login');

Answer (score 1):

You put your controller in a folder so you must call this folder name in Route and in namespace of controller.

Try `"php artisan make:controller foldername/AdminController"`

Your route must be: 
`Route::get('/admin','foldername\AdminController@login')`

And your controller namespace is `namespace App/Http/Controller/foldername`

Comment: but when I create the controller it's not there, I tried to search with its name but there's no result!

Comment: Aha, you use wrong syntax. Try `php artisan make:controller foldername/AdminController`. Replace `foldername\AdminController` to `foldername/AdminController`

Answer (score 0):

For example, by running the command `php artisan make:controller PostController` it will create the
`PostController.php` in `app/Htttp/Controllers`

And you can access in route:

```
Route::get('/posts',  'PostController@index')->name('posts.index');
Route::get('/posts/create',  'PostController@create')->name('posts.create');
Route::post('/posts',  'PostController@store')->name('posts.store');
Route::get('/posts/{post}',  'PostController@show')->name('posts.show');
Route::get('/posts/{post}/edit',  'PostController@edit')->name('posts.edit');
Route::put('/posts/{post}',  'PostController@update')->name('posts.update');
Route::delete('/posts/{post}',  'PostController@destroy')->name('posts.destroy');
```

But in your situation, you are using the custom namespace. For example:

```
php artisan make:controller Admin\PostController
```

It will create the new folder inside the `Controllers` with file:

```
app/Http/Controller/Admin/PostController.php
```

Now you can't access for the route like the previous:

```
Route::get('/posts',  'PostController@index')->name('posts.index');
```

Or

```
Route::resource('/posts',  'PostController');
```

If you are using custom nameSpaces for the large number of controller, try below method:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function () {
    Route::resource('/posts', 'PostController');
});
```

Or:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function () 
{
     Route::get('/posts',  'PostController@index')->name('posts.index');
    Route::get('/posts/create',  'PostController@create')->name('posts.create');
    Route::post('/posts',  'PostController@store')->name('posts.store');
    Route::get('/posts/{post}',  'PostController@show')->name('posts.show');
    Route::get('/posts/{post}/edit',  'PostController@edit')->name('posts.edit');
    Route::put('/posts/{post}',  'PostController@update')->name('posts.update');
    Route::delete('/posts/{post}',  'PostController@destroy')->name('posts.destroy');
});
```